# why did comment header disappear?

Tags: sql-server

Saved a comment header in a stored procedure update script.

```
-- ================================================================================================================================
--  Author:             Ludovic AUBERT
--  creation date:  2019.11.05
--  revision date:
--  Goal:
--  Exemple of call: EXEC myStoredProc ...
--  Description: ...
-- ================================================================================================================================

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[myStoredProc]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[myStoredProc]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[myStoredProc]
AS

BEGIN

SELECT 1

END
```

When I looked at the procedure SQL code in MS SSMS, the comment header was gone !

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[myStoredProc]    Script Date: 21/11/2019 13:27:41 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myStoredProc]
AS

BEGIN

SELECT 1

END
```

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Your comments aren't in the same batch as the one you `CREATE` the SP in.

Comment: I'd say this is more of a reason to use `CREATE OR ALTER` in more recent versions of SQL Sevrer.

Comment: I always wonder where are the comments stored anyway.

Comment: @Larnu, I wish I could

Answer (score 0):

To be stored as part of the procedure SQL code, the header must appear after the DROP PROCEDURE:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[myStoredProc]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[myStoredProc]
GO

-- ================================================================================================================================
--  Author:             Ludovic AUBERT
--  creation date:  2019.11.05
--  revision date:
--  Goal:
--  Exemple of call: EXEC myStoredProc ...
--  Description: ...
-- ================================================================================================================================

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[myStoredProc]
AS

BEGIN

SELECT 1

END
```

Comment: It's not that it needs to appear *"after the DROP PROCEDURE"* it's that it needs to appear at the start of the **batch** the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement is in. Note, for example, that even though the comments are *after* the `DROP` they are still missing in this example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fb4f7bb93bf1cbd000ed7599b722649c).

Comment: To be pedantic, comments are persisted with the stored procedure definition wherever they appear in the `CREATE PROCEDURE` batch. The comments can be before the create statement, inside the stored procedure body, or after the body text.